# Differences in library dependencies between cc_binary and cc_library_shared in android.bp

Tags: android, build, android-source

I'm a newbie to the Android build system and I'm trying to understand the reason behind a particular behavior I've observed. I encountered a dependency issue in android.bp.

When I use **cc_binary** to build an executable test file, having a dependency on the static library **libfs_avb**, the compilation goes smoothly and the executable runs without any issues. However, when I use almost the same logic (just removing the main function used for returning results in the executable) with **cc_library_shared** to build a shared library, I get a plethora of linking errors.

Upon inspecting these errors, they seem to be about undefined symbols. Further investigation revealed that these symbols reside within **libdm**. After several attempts, I managed to successfully compile by explicitly listing all the transitive dependencies (including libdm and its dependency libext2_uuid) to the **cc_library_shared** module.

My question is: Why does the Android build system in android.bp handle transitive dependencies differently when building **cc_library** vs **cc_library_shared**? Or did I perhaps make a mistake that led to this seemingly different build outcome?

While it may not be very useful, here are some linking errors I got when I didn't add transitive dependencies:

```
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: android::dm::DmTargetVerity::UseFec(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)
>>> referenced by avb_util.cpp:85 (system/core/fs_mgr/libfs_avb/avb_util.cpp:85)
>>>               avb_util.o:(android::fs_mgr::ConstructVerityTable(android::fs_mgr::FsAvbHashtreeDescriptor const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, android::dm::DmTable*)) in archive out/soong/.intermediates/system/core/fs_mgr/libfs_avb/libfs_avb/android_arm_armv8-a_static/libfs_avb.a

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: android::dm::DmTargetVerity::SetVerityMode(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)
>>> referenced by avb_util.cpp:90 (system/core/fs_mgr/libfs_avb/avb_util.cpp:90)
>>>               avb_util.o:(android::fs_mgr::ConstructVerityTable(android::fs_mgr::FsAvbHashtreeDescriptor const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, android::dm::DmTable*)) in archive out/soong/.intermediates/system/core/fs_mgr/libfs_avb/libfs_avb/android_arm_armv8-a_static/libfs_avb.a
```